# Can we directly use UserMedia stream as texture source in webgl?

Tags: html5-video, webgl, getusermedia

I have seen a sample that use video tag to send image data from webcam into webgl texture. It then need to create video tag and each frame need to check and update texture

Which sound not so efficient. I'm curious how can we just use stream from getUserMedia to set as texture src. Or any other way to let shader access webcam as texture directly, without creating video tag

Or it not possible?